# Installing Oracle Linux R6U7 SPARC on Sun SPARC Enterprise T5220

Tags: oracle, oracle-linux, ultrasparc

I've booted up the server with burned DVD and installation is stuck in the last row of the displayed log:

```
{0} ok boot cdrom
Boot device: /pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@4/device@4/storage@0/disk@0:f  File and args: 
GRUB Welcome to GRUB!

                          GNU GRUB  version 2.02~beta3

 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |*Install linux using text mode (use DHCP)                                   | 
 | Install linux using VNC (graphical) mode (use DHCP)                        |
 | Rescue mode (use DHCP)                                                     |
 |                                                                            |
 |                                                                            |
 |                                                                            |
 |                                                                            |
 |                                                                            |
 |                                                                            |
 |                                                                            |
 |                                                                            |
 |                                                                            | 
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

      Use the ^ and v keys to select which entry is highlighted.          
      Press enter to boot the selected OS, `e' to edit the commands       
      before booting or `c' for a command-line.                           



PROMLIB: Sun IEEE Boot Prom 'OBP 4.30.2.b 2009/06/16 07:02'
PROMLIB: Root node compatible: sun4v
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Linux version 4.1.12-94.3.4.el6uek.sparc64 (mockbuild@sparc-ol6-builder-04.us.oracle.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16.0.6) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon May 15 13:52:26 PDT 2017
bootconsole [earlyprom0] enabled
ARCH: SUN4V
Ethernet address: 00:14:4f:c4:81:78
MM: PAGE_OFFSET is 0xffff800000000000 (max_phys_bits == 39)
MM: VMALLOC [0x0000000100000000 --> 0x0000600000000000]
MM: VMEMMAP [0x0000600000000000 --> 0x0000c00000000000]
Kernel: Using 4 locked TLB entries for main kernel image.
Remapping the kernel... done.
OF stdout device is: /virtual-devices@100/console@1
PROM: Built device tree with 165901 bytes of memory.
MDESC: Size is 40288 bytes.
PLATFORM: banner-name [SPARC Enterprise T5220]
PLATFORM: name [SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220]
PLATFORM: hostid [84c48178]
PLATFORM: serial# [00ab4130]
PLATFORM: stick-frequency [457646c0]
PLATFORM: mac-address [144fc48178]
PLATFORM: watchdog-resolution [1000 ms]
PLATFORM: watchdog-max-timeout [31536000000 ms]
PLATFORM: max-cpus [64]
Top of RAM: 0x1ffc80000, Total RAM: 0x1f7870000
Memory hole size: 132MB
Allocated 16384 bytes for kernel page tables.
Zone ranges:
  Normal   [mem 0x0000000008400000-0x00000001ffc7ffff]
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
  node   0: [mem 0x0000000008400000-0x00000001ffc6dfff]
  node   0: [mem 0x00000001ffc7e000-0x00000001ffc7ffff]
Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000008400000-0x00000001ffc7ffff]
Booting Linux...
CPU CAPS: [flush,stbar,swap,muldiv,v9,blkinit,n2,mul32]
CPU CAPS: [div32,v8plus,popc,vis,vis2,ASIBlkInit]
PERCPU: Embedded 10 pages/cpu @ffff8001fec00000 s38080 r8192 d35648 u131072
SUN4V: Mondo queue sizes [cpu(8192) dev(16384) r(8192) nr(256)]
Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 1022160
Policy zone: Normal
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz root=/ text ip=dhcp sshd=1 ssh
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 32768 bytes)
Sorting __ex_table...
Memory: 8103736K/8249792K available (6226K kernel code, 2345K rwdata, 2856K rodata, 624K init, 2489K bss, 146056K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
Hierarchical RCU implementation.
        RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=2048 to nr_cpu_ids=64.
RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=64
NR_IRQS:2048 nr_irqs:2048 1
SUN4V: Using IRQ API major 1, cookie only virqs disabled
clocksource stick: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x10cc5ac4c8a, max_idle_ns: 440795218862 ns
clocksource: mult[dbabc5] shift[24]
clockevent: mult[952b25d1] shift[31]
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
console [tty0] enabled
bootconsole [earlyprom0] disabled
```

Has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: The server is crash at that point, means I could even poweroff the server from ILOM (stop /SYS) and had to power it off via power button

Comment: Please use the [`edit`](https://serverfault.com/posts/871017/edit) button below your question rather than comments to update your question with additional information.